# In Resident Evil film series, why does Umbrella continue doing experiments?

Tags: resident-evil

When you kill (or infect) about 95% (or more) of the world's population, and the same virus can infect animals, well, you are doing something wrong. Now, why do you need more powerful monster?

Why do you not use all of your resources to survive this apocalypse? The guards and scientists may have family. If when you have unlimited resources you can't do good things with T-Virus, now that the things are more difficult, you can't continue doing the same things. Why do they continue doing experiments?

Comment: Because without their continued effort, there would be no reason for all the sequels.

Comment: It's worth noting that most of the research in the third movie is aimed at pacifying and controlling the undead, even restoring more of their brain function.

Comment: I think it's called plot-hole induced evil.

Comment: Because science is fun. Science which reanimates the dead is even more fun, because after science kills them, science reanimates them so you can play with them again. "Once you have more money and power than you can ever spend or use, what else is there but mastery over the forces of life and death." Quote from an inner office memo at an Umbrella research facility.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The T-virus is the tail that wags the dog. After the T-virus outbreak, the Umbrella Corp. executives are trying to save themselves. Failure to continue research on the T-virus would ensure their continued isolation and eventual death. During their quest to find a way to stop or regain control of the the T-virus, Umbrella Corps scientists keep opening new cans of worms by creating more zombies, mutants, and Alice clones which continue to erode the Umbrella Corps resources and increases the pressure on the Umbrella Corps research programs. They have to continue the experiments until they either master the T-virus or succumb to it.

Answer (score 3):

The movies have not followed the canon of the games, much less the books.
In the games and books, after the disaster of Raccoon city, Umbrella corp went bankrupt after lawsuits of different governments and civil organizations. 
The United Nations created a department to fight bio-terrorism and biological weapons (I don't remember the name), and in the current plot of the series it's a fight against bio-terrorism.

However the original goal of The Umbrella corp was to create super humans(Wesker is the result in the game, I suppose in the movie it's Alice), then I figured out the goal of Umbrella in the movies it's the same, but  IMHO looks like in that universe the goverments are stupid or corrupt .

In any case the movies don't make much sense, how the hell did the virus evaporate all the water in the planet?

Comment: In the movies the virus didn't evaporate the world's water. In `Afterlife` the movie finishes on the Tanker out in the sea.  Then the setting for the entire `Retribution` film is an underwater compound.

Comment: plot hole, at the start of the third movie alice say that...

Comment: firsts lines..
http://www.script-o-rama.com/movie_scripts/a3/resident-evil-extinction-script-transcript.html

Comment: I took her voiceover at the start of extinction to be hyperbole the land became a wasteland, devoid of life etc

Answer (score 1):

Typical example of a secret or black ops funded organisation, or organisations involved in top secret research, the work and research thy are involved in are so secret, one branch doesn't necessarily know what another is working on, and bad things happen. It's a plot mechanism for many TV series and films.

Some that spring to mind are:

- Umbrella Corporation in the Resident Evil franchise
- Weyland Yutani Corporation in the Aliens franchise
- Massive Dynamics in Fringe
- The secret biotech company in Surface
- The Syndicate in The X-Files

If they didn't do it, they wouldn't have a big bad organisation to focus on as the bad guys.